# Custom WPF Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a custom MarkupExtension that simulates binding. It works well in normal assignments but not when used in Style Setters, for example:

```
<Setter Property="Content" Value="{local:MyExtension}" />
```

results in a XamlParseException:

```
A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Value' property of type 'Setter'.
A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.
```

This is implementation of the extension:

```
public class MyExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public MyExtension()
    {
        Value = 123;
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var binding = new Binding("Value")
        {
            Source = this,
        };
        return binding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
    }
}
```

What's the problem?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kind of guessing, but it's likely because the XAML compiler has special built-in support for the `Binding` class, allowing its usage in this scenario (and others). The `Binding` class is also a `MarkupExtension`, but unfortunately it seals its implementation of `ProvideValue()`.

That said, you might just get away with this:

```
public class MyBinding : Binding
{
    private object value;

    public object Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set
        {
            this.value = value;
            this.Source = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Since `ProvideValue` will return the `Binding` instance anyway.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, it looks like the object must be freezable (so they can be shared between various interested parties)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.setter.value.aspx

> "Data binding and dynamic resources within the object is supported if the specified value is a Freezable object. See Binding Markup Extension and DynamicResource Markup Extension."

Comment: `Binding` isn't `Freezable`. Hence, special support.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you

```
return Value
```

inside the `ProvideValue`??

## else

You can bind to only `DependencyProperty`. make a dependency property for `Value` in your `MyExtension` Class!

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(Object), typeof(MyContentControl), new UIPropertyMetadata());
```