# How to use a PropertyDescriptor instance as part of a Binding definition, rather than using PropertyPath?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding

Consider the following, oversimplified-on-purpose view models:

```
public class GridRowViewModel
{
    public object RowData { get; set; }
    public int RowHeight { get;set; }
    //...
}

public class GridColumnViewModel
{
    public PropertyDescriptor DataFieldDescriptor { get; set; }
    public int ColumnWidth { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

As you may have already guessed, I want viewmodels to manipulate grid-like views from within code, yet keep actual data classes concerns separated. The goal is to allow me to introduce features such as row coloration or multiple row edition mechanisms inside a "proxy" view model that will expose the *real*, unknowing data object as a simple property.

On the XAML side, I'd like to use a column template that does something like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ContentControl>
        <TextBox
             Text="{Binding
                            Source=RowData,
                            Path=(ext:GridCellExtensions.Column.DataFieldDescriptor)}"
        />
    </ContentControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

As you can tell, I reach out to the column instance through an attached property. That part works. I however have no clue on how to tell the binding engine to use its declared, ready-to-use `PropertyDescriptor` instance rather than try to resolve a new one. In fact, I have no clue if this can be done at all.

**So can it be done? If so, how?**

Also please note: the models above are oversimplified for the sake of keeping this post as simple as possible but they're designed this way for reasons that goes beyond the current problem. So proposing a workaround that will force me to rethink this design will most likely create more problems than it solves. Therefore I'm really looking for a solution on the XAML level. If none exists, I'll accept that fact as the answer.

Comment: Where is `ResolvedGridColumnInstance` defined? Is it a property of the `RowData`?

Comment: @MikeEason no it's not. It's actually resolved from an extension. I wanted to keep that out to keep the code as easy to read as possible but I understand how it can be confusing. I'll edit the post.

Comment: just hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441318/custom-wpf-binding

Answer (score -1):

From what I understood you want the path of the binding to be dynamic.

This can be achieved by binding the path property using a Behavior.
e.g:

```
<TextBlock >
     <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
         <behaviors:CustomBindingBehavior PropertyPath="{Binding Path=HeaderPropertyBinding}" IsBinding="{Binding Path=HeaderIsBinding}" />
     </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBlock>
```

I think that this article can help you:

[Binding the path property of a binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524588/binding-the-path-property-of-a-binding)