# WPF ToggleButton multibinding of IsChecked through MarkupExtension throws

Tags: wpf, data-binding, togglebutton, markup-extensions

I am trying to bind the `IsChecked` property of a `ToggleButton` through a markup extension which resolves to a `MultiBinding`. In XAML I have two source toggle buttons and a target toggle button which should have its `IsChecked` bound to the `IsChecked` of the source buttons.

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="Source1" Content="Source 1" Margin="5" Padding="5,2"/>
<ToggleButton x:Name="Source2" Content="Source 2" Margin="5" Padding="5,2"/>

<ToggleButton Content="Target" Margin="5" Padding="5,2">
    <ToggleButton.IsChecked>
        <local:ExMultiBinding  Converter="{StaticResource AnyConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="Source1" Path="IsChecked"/>
            <Binding ElementName="Source2" Path="IsChecked"/>
        </local:ExMultiBinding>
    </ToggleButton.IsChecked>
</ToggleButton>
```

My markup extension providing the `MultiBinding` looks like this

```
[ContentProperty("Bindings")]
public class ExMultiBindingExtension : MarkupExtension, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Collection<BindingBase> Bindings { get; set; } = new Collection<BindingBase>();
    public IMultiValueConverter Converter { get; set; }
    public BindingMode Mode { get; set; }
    public UpdateSourceTrigger UpdateSourceTrigger { get; set; }


    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var multi = new MultiBinding
        {
            Converter = Converter,
            Mode = Mode,
            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger
        };
        return multi;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Starting the UI yields

```
ArgumentException: 'System.Windows.Data.MultiBinding' is not a valid value for property 'IsChecked'.
```

I checked and the `IsChecked` property on the `ToggleButton` implementation is actually not marked with

```
[Bindable(true)]
```

but only with

```
[Category("Appearance")]
[TypeConverter(typeof (NullableBoolConverter))]
[Localizability(LocalizationCategory.None, Readability = Readability.Unreadable)]
```

Direct binding through a `Binding` or `MultiBinding` in XAML works.

The example code is simplified to highlight the problem. It is **not possible to avoid the MarkupExtension** in the real code since the implementation is more complicated.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6441318/1136211)? You may try to derive from MultiBinding instead of MarkupExtension.

Answer (score 0):

`BindingBase` itself is a `MarkupExtension`. And of course a `markupExtension` is not of type `bool` and can't be assigned to a member of type `bool`.

The reason why your extension is called is because the XAML parser wants to resolve every `MarkupExtension`. It's done by invoking the `MarkupExtension.ProvideValue` method. In this case the `BindingBase` object will be associated with a `BindingExpressionBase` object. This `BindingExpressionBase` will resolve the underlying binding to return the actual value (simplified).

So you have to manually resolve the `BindingBase` markup:

```
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
  var multi = new MultiBinding
  {
    Converter = Converter,
    Mode = Mode,
    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger
  };

  // Resolve the MarkupExtension BindingBase
  return multi.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
}
```